# grep - mark this line, which contains even quantity selection

Tags: grep

I would like to mark this line, in which there are even quantity selection. In this case I want to mark even number of digits too.
for example:
for input:

```
22 34 423 22
23213 34 345 23
```

Result should be:

```
22 34 423 22 #<-22 is the marked
```

Comment: if you want to test for an even number of even numbers, then you can't do it with just a regex. You need a programming language, and can use a regex pattern just to capture stuff but then you use the language to count the characters within what you captured, according to your criteria. Perl has one liners and regex support though i'm not that familiar with it.. but grep alone won't do what you want.. maybe piping to another command including `wc -l` or `wc -c` to count how many numbers you got, and a division by 2 testing for a remainder of 0, to see if the count was even.

Comment: though i'm not sure off hand how to do mod at the command line (mod is division and testing remainder)

Comment: I tried use grep with -o, but output contain one letter on one line.

Comment: well fine so if it's one letter on each line you could `| wc -l`    or if you wanted output on one line you could do something like  `| tr -d '\r\n' ` to remove any \r and to remove any \n  And maybe `| wc -c` Though either way, you have the checking if even number issue.  There is echo `4%2|bc` though i'm not sure re echo 4 pipe to something that does %2 to it.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that an "even quantity" always ends with certain digits.

- If lines have several space-separated "quantities":

  ```
  grep -w "[0-9]*[02468]"
  ```
- If you want to check only the last digit:

  ```
  grep "[02468]$"
  ```

For an "even number of even numbers"...

```
perl -a -n -e 'print if (grep {/^[0-9]*[02468]$/} @F) % 2 == 0'
```

Comment: I mean an even number of even numbers.

Answer (score 0):

For bash, try this:

```
$ n=2; while [ $n -lt 10 ]; do \
grep -E "2{$n}|4{$n}|6{$n}|8{$n}|0{$n}" <IN_FILE; n=$(( n+2 )); done
```

But as you can see it won't give you all from a single run/regexp though, so if you're to use it from your own software/script you need to adapt it.